# How to sync data between two Elasticache Redis Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, data-migration, amazon-elasticache

I have two AWS Elasticache instances, One of the instances (lets say `instance A`) has very important data sets and connections on it, downtime is unacceptable. Because of this situation, instead of doing normal migration (like preventing source data from new writes, getting dump on it, and restore it to the new one) I'm trying to sync `instance A`'s data to another Elasticache instance (lets say `instance B`). As I said, this process should be `downtime-free`. In order to do that, I tried [RedisShake](https://github.com/alibaba/RedisShake), but because AWS restrict users to run certain [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html) (`bgsave`, `config`, `replicaof`,`slaveof`,`sync` etc), RedisShake is not working with AWS Elasticache.  It's giving the error below.

```
2022/04/04 11:58:42 [PANIC] invalid psync response, continue, ERR unknown command `psync`, with args beginning with: `?`, `-1`, 
[stack]: 
    2   github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/common/utils.go:252
            github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/common.SendPSyncContinue
    1   github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/dbSync/syncBegin.go:51
            github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/dbSync.(*DbSyncer).sendPSyncCmd
    0   github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/dbSync/dbSyncer.go:113
            github.com/alibaba/RedisShake/redis-shake/dbSync.(*DbSyncer).Sync
        ... ...
```

I've tried [rump](https://github.com/stickermule/rump) for that matter, But it doesn't have enough stability to handle any important processes. First of all, it's not working as a background process, when the first sync finished, it's being closed with `signal: exit done`, so it will not be getting ongoing changes after the first finish.
Second of all, it's recognizing created/modified `key/values` in each run, for example, in first run key `apple` equals to `pear`, it's synced to the destination as is, but when I deleted the key `apple` and its value in source and ran the `rump` syncing script again, it's not being deleted in destination. So basically it's not literally syncing the source and the destination. Plus, last commit to the `rump` github repo is about 3 years ago. It seems a little bit outdated project to me.

After all this information and attempts, my question is, is there a way to sync two `Elasticache for Redis` instances, as I said, there is no room for downtime in my case. If you guys with this kind of experience have a bulletproof suggestion, I would be much appreciated. I tried but unfortunately didn't find any.

Thank you very much,

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The [document](https://tair-opensource.github.io/RedisShake/en/guide/mode.html#aws-elasticache-and-memorydb) of RedisShake has already explained for this situation:

> `sync_reader` is preferred. AWS ElastiCache and MemoryDB do not enable
> the PSync protocol by default, but you can request to enable the PSync
> protocol by submitting a ticket. AWS will provide a renamed PSync
> command in the ticket, such as `xhma21yfkssync` and `nmfu2bl5osync`.
> This command has the same effect as the `psync` command, just with a
> different name. Users only need to modify the `aws_psync`
> configuration item in the RedisShake configuration file. For a single
> instance, write one pair of `ip:port@cmd`. For cluster instances,
> write all `ip:port@cmd`, separated by commas.
>
> When it is inconvenient to submit a ticket, you can use `scan_reader`.
> It should be noted that `scan_reader` will put significant pressure on
> the source database.

I recommend that you try submitting a support ticket.

Alternatively, you can try enabling [KSN support](https://tair-opensource.github.io/RedisShake/en/reader/scan_reader.html) in scan mode to obtain incremental data.

Answer (score 0):

If those two Elasticache Redis clusters exist in the same account but different regions, you can consider using AWS Elasticache global-datastore.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Redis-Global-Datastores-Console.html

It has some restrictions on the regions, type of nodes and that both the clusters should have same configurations in terms of number of nodes, etc.

Limitations - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Redis-Global-Datastores-Getting-Started.html

Otherwise, there's a simple brute-force mechanism and you would be able to code it yourself I believe.

1. Create a client EC2 (let's call this Sync-er) pub-sub channel from your EC Redis instance A.
2. Whenever there is a new data, Sync-er would make WRITE commands on EC Redis instance B.

NOTE - You'll have to make sure that the clusters are in connectable VPCs.
Elasticache is only available to the resources within the VPC. If your Instance A and Instance B are in different VPCs, you'll have to peer them or connect them via TransitGateway.